# Sorting using comparisons that are not simple mappings of simple comparisons

Tags: complexity-classes, soft-question, time-complexity

The Python language has a *sort(x)* function that sorts a list based on the intrinsic comparison operator associated with the type of the elements of its input list *x*.  One can also provide a *cmp* argument (*sort(x, cmp=f)*), which is a two-parameter function that will be used to compare pairs of elements of *x*.  In general, the *cmp* function will be called $O(len(x) \log len(x))$ times.

More efficiently, one can provide a *key* argument (*sort(x, key=f)*), which will be called $O(len(x))$ times to transform each element of *x* into "key values" which will then be compared by the intrinsic comparison operator associated with the type of the key values.

A developer of the *key* feature has asserted that using *key* is always more efficient than using *cmp*.  This leads to a somewhat amorphous atheoretical question:

Does there exist a universe of values $U$ which can be compared by a "fast" algorithm but for which there is no "fast" algorithm which maps elements of $U$ in an order-preserving way into elements of a "simple" key set $K$ which can be compared by a "fast" algorithm?  I assume that all the orders are total orders.  The exact meaning of "simple" is unclear to me, but my intuition is that "finite sequences of integers under lexicographic ordering" is a superset of all totally-ordered sets that I would consider "simple".  The condition of "simplicity" is what excludes the trivial solution of setting $K = U$ and using the identity as the key mapping, and the simplicity of $K$'s comparison function is what excludes having the key mapping simply encode elements of $U$ into $K$ in some straightforward way.

In a sense, what I'm looking for is a total ordering which is not a "simple" transformation of "simple" totally-ordered set.